# Pricing for aws ec2 instance volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I couldn't find any documentation on pricing for EC2 instance's instance volume. Without looking at the AWS Management Console, I am pretty much sure that AWS will not charge for the instance volumes on top of the charges for the EC2 instance itself. Please confirm.

Thanks!

Comment: are you referring to ec2's ebs volumne or instance store volume?

Comment: Why woudn't they charge your? You try to use AWS Free tier discounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) for **EBS** AWS **Free Tier** includes 30GB of Storage, 2 million I/Os, and 1GB of snapshot storage with Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS). But if you go beyond free tier then for specific volume type it differs

for example in US East region.

```
General Purpose SSD (gp3) - Storage $0.08/GB-month
```

For **instance store volumes.**

*The cost of an EC2 instance includes any local instance store volumes, if the instance type provides them. Although there is no additional charge for data storage on local instance store volumes,note that data transferred to and from Amazon EC2 instance store volumes from other Availability Zones or outside of an Amazon EC2 Region can incur data transfer charges.* [docs for reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-storage-services-overview/cost-model-4.html),
[Ec2 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)

Comment: Thanks for confirming @Jatin Mehrotra! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: if it helped can you accept it as answer so that it may help others in the future :)

Comment: Done Jatin.  Thanks!